# Understanding why Windows boot fails when EFI partition is moved

Tags: windows, boot, gpt, efi

## Situation

I got a new computer with a HDD. I put SSDs in it and made RAID1, then started installing Windows Server 2022. I wanted to use SSDs and a HDD for data. I noticed the HDD already had some partition on it, probably DOS, because I purchased separate license - computer didn't come with one. I didn't pay much attention and installed the thing.

Now that all was installed, I noticed EFI partition is on the HDD, while all the other partitions are on RAID1. In this situation, when I would remove HDD, Windows would stop loading.

Because all the disks were GPT and I learned there's no bootblock that needs to be copied, just the EFI partition is needed to point boot process to the proper partition with Windows, I surmised it would suffice to use Macrium Reflect Free to copy the partition in the proper order to the RAID1 disks. So I went with imaging both HDD and RAID1, disconnected the former and started to copy partitions from both disk images back to previously cleaned RAID1 SSDs. First was EFI, then this hidden partition and finally normal disk C:

## Result and Desired result

The boot failed with a BSOD and error code I don't remember, auto-repair or repair from CD didn't work. Because I was pressed on time, I just reinstalled the whole server from scratch, but now I want to understand what actually went wrong. From what I understand GPT, disks don't use boot sectors so this should work. Before doing anything I freshened my knowledge about EFI boot process from GPT disks and all that was needed for the boot to succeed seemed to be in the right place.

Please help me understand what did I do wrong.

Comment: There's no problem in having the ESP in a different drive as long as the boot priority is set correctly.

Comment: You have to point to the correct disk that contains the EFI partition. Simply copying the partition isn’t enough

Comment: So this is the part I didn't understand correctly. Does Windows installation process (not only Windows) write something to the NVRAM on the mainboard? Like this string for example: Value: HD(2,GPT,025456D1-E741-4932-B83B-6869DCC4B8E3,0xFA000,0x31800)/\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi

Firmware device path: HD(2,GPT,025456D1-E741-4932-B83B-6869DCC4B8E3,0xFA000,0x31800)/\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
and if so, is this the part that @Ramhound is referring to, that needs to be corrected?

Comment: Yes; The unique partition id is clearly indicated in that string including the disk number. Problem with asking questions in the comment section is they contain no formatting and are difficult to read

Comment: That's also a problem with *answering* questions in the comment section...